# Start CLLocationManager while in background

Tags: iphone, ios, cllocationmanager, background-process

Is it possible to "suspend" the cllocationmanager while in the background?

I'm trying to stop the manager then restart it at a specific time all while in the background.  Is this possible?  I tried stopping the manager and starting a nstimer, but it doesn't work because nstimer does not run while in the background.

My objective is to have the manager run during certain time intervals, "suspend" during certain time intervals, and start after the suspend time is up in order to preserve battery life.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: No.

The long answer is: Apple has thought of that and has a solution for you.

You should read about [App States and Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) and look for "Tracking the User’s Location" subtitle.

Comment: What do you mean by "Apple has thought of that and has a solution for you"?  I've read that article and the "Location Awareness Programming Guide".  I cannot use significant changes because it does not provide the precision and accuracy that I need.

Comment: then, as mentioned, use the `UIBackgroundModes` to give you more than the ~10 minutes of background time, it's not guaranteed